# Nullable nested type in extension method in C#

Tags: c#, nullable

I am trying to make a super cool extension for `IDictionary` - `GetValue` with a default value that is null if not set. Here is the code I came up with (doesn't work):

```
public static TValue GetValue<TKey, TValue> (this IDictionary<TKey,
    TValue> dictionary, TKey key, TValue defaultValue = null)
{
    TValue value;
    return dictionary.TryGetValue(key, out value)
        ? value
        : defaultValue;
}
```

How to make this for `nullables` only? (like, don't include `int`, etc).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You mean for `reference types` only. Add `where T: class` as follows:

```
public static TValue GetValue<TKey, TValue> (this IDictionary<TKey,
    TValue> dictionary, TKey key, TValue defaultValue = null)
    where TValue: class
{
```

However you can make this work with value types too, by using `default(TValue)` to specify the default:

```
public static TValue GetValue<TKey, TValue>(this IDictionary<TKey,
    TValue> dictionary, TKey key, TValue defaultValue = default(TValue))
{
    TValue value;
    return dictionary.TryGetValue(key, out value)
        ? value
        : defaultValue;
}
```

Of course, only do this if you actually WANT it to work with all possible types, rather than just with reference types.

Comment: Good clarification to the OP on what the restriction really intends to do.  `nullable` implies they must be reference types.

Answer (score 2):

You can use constraints on your type parameters ([MSDN Type Constraints](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5x73970.aspx)). What you want here is the `class` constraint, like so:

```
public static TValue GetValue<TKey, TValue> (this IDictionary<TKey,
TValue> dictionary, TKey key, TValue defaultValue = null) where TValue : class
```

This works for reference types, which is what you really want. Nullable would imply something like `int?` working as well.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [class constraint](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5x73970.aspx):

```
public static TValue GetValue<TKey, TValue> (this IDictionary<TKey,
    TValue> dictionary, TKey key, TValue defaultValue = null) where TValue : class
{
    TValue value;
    return dictionary.TryGetValue(key, out value)
        ? value
        : defaultValue;
}
```

Comment: Note: The class constraint should be on `TValue` not `TKey`